# When to use fragments over views?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I read the fragments tutorial, but I still don't understand why they are actually needed. The tutorial gives the example of the 2 fragments in a wide screen and 2 activities in a small one, but I actually could just use a view and put it in the same activity or in another activity to achieve the same effect, so what does a fragment give me that a simple view doesn't? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fragment has a life cycle of its own , so you don't have to worry about memory and objects in larger screens where this does matter.

Comment: The whole lifecycle and backstack issue sounds much more complex to deal with than working with sub-views. I'm still looking for an advantage of this method over adding and removing views. Does the user really need the back button functionality to navigate fragment transactions? In my opinion it's actually very confusing to work with an application like that...

Comment: Subviews mean you have to override the life cycle of the parent activity. It's useful if you need a small portion of the screen with its own lifecycle, e.g. mainly if you want split-screen on your app to 'have a mind of its own'. If you don't need it, you should avoid using it.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand why sub-views (not fragments) force me to override the life-cycle of the parent activity. A view is part of the layout of the activity. I may be missing something here...

Comment: Oh, you're right, @user940016. I was thinking of it from a fragment usage and forgot that you can access+destroy them from within the activity lifecycle itself. I guess it's more of a design option; a fragment is a separate object that acts similarly to an activity.

Answer (score 1):

They're suitable when you want to put different content for different types of layouts. Mainly for building an app that's suited to both tablets and phones.

[image]

Think of a Fragment like a different activity within the same screen. Sometimes it's easier to have the code itself to be controlled within the fragment, rather than in a master Activity, especially if you intend to split them into separate layouts.

Things like Fragment dialogs are also more powerful than classic Dialogs. Communicating information to a fragment is a little easier and more efficient than between activities (though this may vary according to situation).

If you don't have a reason to use them or don't feel like experimenting, go as simple as possible. There's quite a bit of overhead to Fragments, so unless you're designing for multiple layouts (mainly tablets), it's more work for little gain.

Comment: That's the example from the tutorial, but as I said, I could achieve this effect by using the same sub-view in each of the layouts.